# Select option element JavaScript Console

Tags: javascript, html, click, html-lists

I want to select 100 from list JavaScript, I'm trying this from console

```
<div class="dataTables_length" id="Table_6_length">
 <label>
     <select name="DataTables_Table" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_6" class="form-control input-sm">
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="50">50</option>
              <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
</label></div>
```

I'm new in JavaScript Please help me

Comment: ```document.querySelector("[name='DataTables_Table']").value = "100";```

Comment: @Rayon Tried this but i want to trigger event on option select

Comment: that doesn't make any sense.  If someone selects 20 you want to select 100?

Comment: Please, edit your question about what you really trying to make: choose an value and dispatch an event related to value, choose a valeu and disptach an event related to "100" or other.

Answer (score 0):

Give a Id to the `select`
Then it's as simple as
`document.getElementById('selecter').value=100;`

[refer this.](https://jsfiddle.net/CharlesRajendran/vgL7hrqs/7/)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `.value` property for `dropdown element`

```js
function selectOption(val) {

  document.getElementById('dataTable').value = val;

}
```

```html
<select name="DataTables_Table" id='dataTable' aria-controls="DataTables_Table_6" class="form-control input-sm">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    
    <button onclick='selectOption("100")'>select 100</button>
    <button onclick='selectOption("50")'>select 50</button>
    <button onclick='selectOption("25")'>select 25</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop options for your option like this

```
let sel = document.getElementsByName('DataTables_Table')[0];

function getSelectedOption(sel) {
    var opt;
    for ( var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        opt = sel.options[i];
        if ( opt.value == 100 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return opt;
}

let opt100 = getSelectedOption(sel);
console.log(opt100)
console.log(opt100.value)
```

```js
let sel = document.getElementsByName('DataTables_Table')[0];

function getSelectedOption(sel) {
    var opt;
    for ( var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        opt = sel.options[i];
        if ( opt.value == 100 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return opt;
}

let opt100 = getSelectedOption(sel);
console.log(opt100)
console.log(opt100.value)
```

```html
<div class="dataTables_length" id="Table_6_length">
 <label>
     <select name="DataTables_Table" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_6" class="form-control input-sm">
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="50">50</option>
              <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
</label></div>
```